# Segmentation fault in vector for loop-malloc.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm getting a segmentation fault in the following code for a greedy algorithm for the knapsack problem. I've never successfully solved a segmentation fault before, though I've seen them, so I'd appreciate some help.

The message I get when I run the debugger is that there is no "malloc.c". When I run valgrind, I get an "Invalid read of size 4". Between that and the nature of the bug, I'm guessing I'm trying to access a vector element that is nonexistant. But I've tried every way I could think of to try and make sure that the loop didn't overstep its bounds when iterating through the vector.

(I've done this without using a C++11 range-based for loop and still get the same error. It doesn't seem to matter what I choose for the parameters of the for loop, it still throws a segmentation error.)

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

bool decreaseSort(int a, int b)
{
   return a > b;   //sort by decreasing value for better performance
}

double get_optimal_value(int capacity, vector<int> weights, vector<int> values) {

sort(weights.begin(),weights.end(), decreaseSort); 
sort(values.begin(),weights.end(), decreaseSort);

vector<int> ourKnapsack(values.size(), 0);

double totalValue = 0.0;
int ourInput = 0;

for (auto i : ourKnapsack){
  int ourValue = values.at(i);
  int ourWeight = weights.at(i);
  double unitValue = (double)ourValue/ourWeight;
  if (capacity == 0) 
      return totalValue;


  if (weights.at(i) < capacity){
      ourInput = weights.at(i);
  }
  else {
      ourInput = capacity;
  }


  totalValue = totalValue * (ourInput * unitValue); 
  weights.at(i)-=ourInput;
  ourKnapsack.at(i)+=ourInput;
  capacity-=ourInput;

 }
 return totalValue;
}

  int main() {
  int n = 3;
  int capacity = 50;

  vector<int> values(n);
  values = {60,100,120};
  vector<int> weights(n); 
  weights = {20,50,30};

  double optimal_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values);

  std::cout.precision(10);
  std::cout << optimal_value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was so utterly focused on the code dealing with the vector and the loop because I saw the word "segmentation", but neglected to look at sort... thank you.

Comment: This is what "undefined behavior" means. It doesn't mean "an immediate segmentation fault". It means "from this point on, anything can happen". An immediate segmentation fault would be one possibility. The code limping along, for some time, and then blowing up later, is also another possibility, also fully qualified as "undefined behavior". Welcome to C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
sort(values.begin(),weights.end(), decreaseSort);
```

That's your problem, right there. Oops.

Obviously, it should be `values.end()`, not `weights.end()`.